# Type to edit in TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview

**Problem**

I'd like to switch to edit mode in my TableView as soon as I type. I don't want to doubleclick or press to enter on each and every cell first, that's annoying.

I've come up with the following piece of code. Problem is that it is more or less side-effect programming and I suspect troubles. When you use KEY_RELEASED in order to switch the table into edit mode, the 1st key press gets lost.

So you have to use KEY_PRESSED. It all seems to work fine now, but once in a while you get a race condition and the caret in the TextField cell editor is before the typed text instead of after it. But when you continue typing, then the text gets appended correctly after the existing text.

It appears okay, but from a developing point of view it seems like a mess with race conditions.

**Question**

Does anyone have a proper way of doing a "type-to-edit" functionality?

**Code**

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
public class InlineEditingTableView extends Application {

    private final ObservableList<Data> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Data(1.,5.),
                new Data(2.,6.),
                new Data(3.,7.),
                new Data(4.,8.)
        );

    private TableView<Data> table;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // create edtiable table
        table = new TableView<Data>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        // column 1 contains numbers
        TableColumn<Data, Number> number1Col = new TableColumn<>("Number 1");
        number1Col.setMinWidth(100);
        number1Col.setCellValueFactory( cellData -> cellData.getValue().number1Property());
        number1Col.setCellFactory( createNumberCellFactory());
        number1Col.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Data, Number>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Data, Number> t) {
                System.out.println( t);
//                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });

        // column 2 contains numbers
        TableColumn<Data, Number> number2Col = new TableColumn<>("Number 2");
        number2Col.setMinWidth(100);
        number2Col.setCellValueFactory( cellData -> cellData.getValue().number2Property());
        number2Col.setCellFactory( createNumberCellFactory());

        // add columns & data to table
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll( number1Col, number2Col);




        // switch to edit mode on keypress
        // this must be KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED so that the key gets forwarded to the editing cell; it wouldn't be forwarded on KEY_RELEASED
        table.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

                if( event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
//                  event.consume(); // don't consume the event or else the values won't be updated;
                    return;
                }

                // switch to edit mode on keypress, but only if we aren't already in edit mode
                if( table.getEditingCell() == null) {
                    if( event.getCode().isLetterKey() || event.getCode().isDigitKey()) {  

                        TablePosition focusedCellPosition = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
                        table.edit(focusedCellPosition.getRow(), focusedCellPosition.getTableColumn());

                    }
                }

            }
        });

        table.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

                if( event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    table.getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell();
                }
            }
        });     

        // single cell selection mode
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();




        // add nodes to stage
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 800,600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Number cell factory which converts strings to numbers and vice versa.
     * @return
     */
    private Callback<TableColumn<Data, Number>, TableCell<Data, Number>>  createNumberCellFactory() {

        Callback<TableColumn<Data, Number>, TableCell<Data, Number>> factory = TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn( new StringConverter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public Number fromString(String string) {
                return Double.parseDouble(string);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString(Number object) {
                return object.toString();
            }
        });

        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * Table data container
     */
    public static class Data {

        private final SimpleDoubleProperty number1;
        private final SimpleDoubleProperty number2;

        private Data( Double number1, Double number2) {
            this.number1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(number1);
            this.number2 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(number2);
        }

        public final DoubleProperty number1Property() {
            return this.number1;
        }

        public final double getNumber1() {
            return this.number1Property().get();
        }

        public final void setNumber1(final double number1) {
            this.number1Property().set(number1);
        }

        public final DoubleProperty number2Property() {
            return this.number2;
        }

        public final double getNumber2() {
            return this.number2Property().get();
        }

        public final void setNumber2(final double number2) {
            this.number2Property().set(number2);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

To edit immediately on clicking a cell, it makes more sense to me to have the `TextField`s permanently displayed in the table, instead of transitioning to a special "edit mode" and switch from a `Label` to a `TextField`. (I would think of this as having all cells always in "edit mode", which I think makes sense with the behavior you want.)

If that kind of UI works for your requirements, you can just render text fields in the cell and bind bidirectionally the text field's `textProperty` to the appropriate property in your model. The tricky part here is getting hold of that property: you have to go from the cell to the table row, then to the item for the table row, and then to the property you need. At any time, one of those may change (possibly to `null`), so you have to deal with those possibilities.

Give the usual example:

```
public class Person {

    // ...

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() { ... }

    // etc...
}
```

You can do

```
    TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
    firstNameCol.setCellFactory(col -> {
        TableCell<Person, String> cell = new TableCell<>();
        TextField textField = new TextField();

        cell.graphicProperty().bind(Bindings.when(cell.emptyProperty())
                .then((Node)null)
                .otherwise(textField));

        ChangeListener<Person> rowItemListener = (obs, oldPerson, newPerson) -> {
            if (oldPerson != null) {
                textField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(((Person) oldPerson).firstNameProperty());
            }
            if (newPerson != null) {
                textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(((Person) newPerson).firstNameProperty());
            }
        };
        cell.tableRowProperty().addListener((obs, oldRow, newRow) -> {
            if (oldRow != null) {
                oldRow.itemProperty().removeListener(rowItemListener);
                if (oldRow.getItem() != null) {
                    textField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(((Person) oldRow.getItem()).firstNameProperty());
                }
            }
            if (newRow != null) {
                newRow.itemProperty().addListener(rowItemListener);
                if (newRow.getItem() != null) {
                    textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(((Person) newRow.getItem()).firstNameProperty());
                }
            }
        });

        return cell ;
    });
```

You can greatly reduce the code complexity here by using the EasyBind framework, which provides (among other things) ways to get "properties of properties" with appropriate handling for `null`:

```
    TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
    firstNameCol.setCellFactory(col -> {
        TableCell<Person, String> cell = new TableCell<>();
        TextField textField = new TextField();

        cell.graphicProperty().bind(Bindings.when(cell.emptyProperty())
                .then((Node)null)
                .otherwise(textField));

        textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(
                EasyBind.monadic(cell.tableRowProperty())
                .selectProperty(TableRow::itemProperty)
                .selectProperty(p -> ((Person)p).firstNameProperty()));

        return cell ;
    });
```

Here is a complete example, where I factored the cell factory code above into a more general method:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.fxmisc.easybind.EasyBind;

public class LiveTableViewCell extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getItems().addAll(            
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

        table.getColumns().addAll(
            createColumn("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty),
            createColumn("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty),
            createColumn("Email", Person::emailProperty)
        );

        Button button = new Button("Debug");
        button.setOnAction(e -> table.getItems().stream().map(p -> String.format("%s %s %s", p.getFirstName(), p.getLastName(), p.getEmail())).forEach(System.out::println));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table, null, null, button, null), 600, 120));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TableColumn<Person, String> createColumn(String title, Function<Person, Property<String>> property) {
        TableColumn<Person, String> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));

        col.setCellFactory(column -> {
            TableCell<Person, String> cell = new TableCell<>();
            TextField textField = new TextField();

        // Example of maintaining selection behavior when text field gains
        // focus. You can also call getSelectedCells().add(...) on the selection
        // model if you want to maintain multiple selected cells, etc.

        textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isFocused) -> {
            if (isFocused) {
                cell.getTableView().getSelectionModel().select(cell.getIndex(), cell.getTableColumn());
            }
        });

        cell.graphicProperty().bind(Bindings.when(cell.emptyProperty())
                .then((Node)null)
                .otherwise(textField));

            // If not using EasyBind, you need the following commented-out code in place of the next statement:

//          ChangeListener<Person> rowItemListener = (obs, oldPerson, newPerson) -> {
//               if (oldPerson != null) {
//                   textField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(property.apply((Person)oldPerson));
//               }
//               if (newPerson != null) {
//                   textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(property.apply((Person)newPerson));
//               }
//            };
//            cell.tableRowProperty().addListener((obs, oldRow, newRow) -> {
//                if (oldRow != null) {
//                    oldRow.itemProperty().removeListener(rowItemListener);
//                    if (oldRow.getItem() != null) {
//                        textField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(property.apply((Person)oldRow.getItem()));
//                    }
//                }
//                if (newRow != null) {
//                    newRow.itemProperty().addListener(rowItemListener);
//                    if (newRow.getItem() != null) {
//                        textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(property.apply((Person)newRow.getItem()));
//                    }
//                }
//            });

            textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(EasyBind.monadic(cell.tableRowProperty())
                    .selectProperty(TableRow::itemProperty)
                    .selectProperty(p -> (property.apply((Person)p))));

            return cell ;
        });
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setEmail(email);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final java.lang.String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final java.lang.String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getEmail() {
            return this.emailProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setEmail(final java.lang.String email) {
            this.emailProperty().set(email);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

(The annoying downcasts here are because `TableCell<S,T>.getTableRow()` returns a raw `TableRow` object, instead of a `TableRow<S>`, for reasons I have never understood.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate the effort. But if I'd choose your solution, then I'd lose the option to select and e. g. copy/paste table cells.

Comment: Actually, you can still select cells, though it is admittedly difficult: you need to click in the cell but outside the text field (there is by default a tiny amount of space there). But you can also just add a focus listener to the text field and set the cell as selected when it gains focus. See update in full example.

Comment: Thanks, but It's not intuitive. We are trying to replace Swing with JavaFX. We have heavy table usage. And what I've seen so far JavaFX lacks what one would expect from a table. I guess that's why it' called tableVIEW and not TableEditor. Basically our users want what they are used with Excel. I'm still wondering why Oracle didn't implement the table this way. I did try the SpreadsheetView. But that already failed when I couldn't even display the example in the ControlsFX sampler jar. Must be some Java version thing, because it worked some months ago. Your input is always appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can avoid it by implementing custom text field tablecell, where you can put the caret at the end of the item text manually on entering edit mode.

Another approach is to enter edit mode on focus:

```
table.getFocusModel().focusedCellProperty().addListener(
        ( ObservableValue<? extends TablePosition> observable, TablePosition oldValue, TablePosition newValue ) ->
        {
            if ( newValue != null )
            {
                Platform.runLater( () ->
                        {
                            table.edit( newValue.getRow(), newValue.getTableColumn() );
                } );
            }
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

a couple of years late, but I actually found a solution to this (using a Robot).

```
    this.setOnKeyTyped(x -> {

            String typed = x.getCharacter();
        
//can make editing start only when certain keys (e.g. digits) are typed.
            if(typed != null && typed.matches("[0-9]")) {
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                robot.keyPress(KeyCode.ENTER);
            }

        });
```